# How can I properly leverage Firestore realtime updates in swift using the onSnapshot() method?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm new to Google Firestore and swift generally, and am wondering how to properly set up a onSnapshot() method so my view controller can receive updates automatically and to fit all situations.

I have a very simple struct (Llama) that I am using to model my data. I was able to build a rudimentary Firestore setup by following this excellent tutorial: (https://youtu.be/XwXEsKRYUXU)

However, I've found that in implementing my own version of the code, I only know how to allow for document creation on the server. I would like to be able to update an object in my app if it changes on the server, and I would like to be able to delete one also. I'm currently at a loss on how to accomplish this.

Additionally, when it comes to updating objects in my app, is there a way to update only the fields that changed, as opposed to overwriting the entire object.

What I would like to be able to accomplish is a database model that syncs seamlessly between the hosted server and a user's device in the background, merging anyone's changes together if there is ever a conflict (resolved by who modified the document last.)

I've read Google's documentation exhaustively on the subject, and even though I'm certain the answers are there, I'm personally not yet at a level with swift where I can understand them fully: (https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/how-to)

Data Model:

```
import Foundation
import Firebase

protocol DocumentSerializable {
    init?(dictionary:[String:Any])
}

struct Llama {

    var name: String
    var color: String
    var gender: String

    init(name: String, color: String, gender: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.color = color
        self.gender = gender
    }

    var dictionary:[String:Any] {
        return [
            "name":name,
            "color":color,
            "gender":gender
        ]
    }

}

extension Llama:DocumentSerializable {
    init? (dictionary: [String:Any]) {
        guard
            let name = dictionary["name"] as? String,
            let color = dictionary["color"] as? String,
            let gender = dictionary["gender"] as? String
            else {return nil}
        self.init(name: name, color: color, gender: gender)
    }
}
```

View Controller Code:

```
    var llamas = [Llama]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        checkForUpdates()
    }

    func checkForUpdates() {
        let firestore = Firestore.firestore()
        firestore.collection("Llama").addSnapshotListener{
            QuerySnapshot, error in
            guard let snapshot = QuerySnapshot else {return}
            snapshot.documentChanges.forEach {
                update in
                if update.type == .added {
                    self.llamas.append(Llama(dictionary: update.document.data())!) // Works great!
                }
                if update.type == .modified {
                    // How can I update the correct llama object, hopefully just the field(s) that changed?
                }
                if update.type == .removed {
                    // How can I remove the correct llama object?
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

As indicated in the View Controller code, I have a function that gets called when the view controller opens that initializes an addSnapShotListener() method. The code as is doesn't run with any errors or warnings. How can I move forward?

Comment: It sounds like you want to listen for changes to your database when something is added, modified or removed. The documentation covers that [View changes between snapshots](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#view_changes_between_snapshots)

Comment: Thanks! I was aware of this page starting out, but it's good to know I'm focusing on the right part of the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several parts to the question and it would be a very long(er) answer to address all of them. Here's a solution that will initially load your dataSource array and then watch and handle added, modified and removed events for discreet 'objects' e.g. documents.

For this example, we'll use an app that tracks favorite wines across devices. We keep track of the wine name, the State where's it's made and a rating.

The structure is this

```
wines
   doc_0
      name: "Insignia"
      rating: "98"
      state: "CA"
   doc_1
      name: "Quilceda Creek"
      rating: "99"
      state: "WA"
```

doc_0, doc_1 etc are the document id's that are automatically created when adding a document.

Then we need a class to hold each wine

```
class WineClass {
    var wine_id = ""
    var name = ""
    var rating = ""
    var state = ""

    init(withDoc: QueryDocumentSnapshot) {
        self.wine_id = withDoc.documentID
        self.name = withDoc.get("name") as? String ?? "no name"
        self.rating = withDoc.get("rating") as? String ?? "no rating"
        self.state = withDoc.get("state") as? String ?? "no state"
    }

    func updateProperties(withDoc: QueryDocumentSnapshot) {
        self.name = withDoc.get("name") as? String ?? "no name"
        self.rating = withDoc.get("rating") as? String ?? "no rating"
        self.state = withDoc.get("state") as? String ?? "no state"
    }
}
```

and finally a class var Array that will act as a dataSource for a tableView or collectionView.

```
var wineArray = [WineClass]()
```

Then the code - we are only interested in wines from CA so the query limits the result to just those for this example.

```
func handleSpecificChanges() {
    let collectionRef = self.db.collection("wines")
    collectionRef.whereField("state", isEqualTo: "CA").addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, error in
        guard let snapshot = querySnapshot else {
            print("Error fetching snapshots: \(error!)")
            return
        }

        snapshot.documentChanges.forEach { diff in
            if (diff.type == .added) {
                let wineToAdd = WineClass(withDoc: diff.document)
                self.wineArray.append(wineToAdd)
                print("added: \(wineToAdd.wine_id)  \(wineToAdd.name) \(wineToAdd.rating)  \(wineToAdd.state)")
            }
            if (diff.type == .modified) {
                let docId = diff.document.documentID
                if let indexOfWineToModify = self.wineArray.firstIndex(where: { $0.wine_id == docId} ) {
                    let wineToModify = self.wineArray[indexOfWineToModify]
                    wineToModify.updateProperties(withDoc: diff.document)
                    print("modified: \(wineToModify.wine_id)  \(wineToModify.name) \(wineToModify.rating)  \(wineToModify.state)")
                }
            }
            if (diff.type == .removed) {
                let docId = diff.document.documentID
                if let indexOfWineToRemove = self.wineArray.firstIndex(where: { $0.wine_id == docId} ) {
                    self.wineArray.remove(at: indexOfWineToRemove)
                    print("removed: \(docId)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

A few notes

The docId (doc_0, doc_1) etc is the key that holds it all together. It's guaranteed to be unique and is how you know which wine has been modified or removed, and is assigned when the wine is created in Firestore.

When this code initially runs, the .added is called for each wine that matches the query. This allows you to initially populate your dataSource array with matches and will watch for added events thereafter.

One of your questions was updating a field of an object without totally overwriting it. That may not be super important - as you can see from the modified event, we simply pass the current fields to the object to update all of the fields. If you really wanted to not 'overwrite' fields you could add an if check to see if the field data passed in is different than what it was.

```
if self.rating != newRatnig {
   self.rating == newRating
}
```

but again, that's probably not necessary.

I think that addresses everything in the question.

Comment: Thank you for the very comprehensive response. I think I understand how this stuff works a lot better now. I think at the end of the day I was struggling with the swift side of things more than Firestore itself. Once I took this course on Pluralsight things really started clicking: (https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/swift3-fundamentals/table-of-contents) For beginners who are struggling with the Swift language, I can't recommend this course any higher. Worth every penny.